# Why does a background process, started in bash, print stdout to screen?

Tags: linux, bash, debian-jessie

I have trouble understanding my situation and Google was not very helpful so far.

I started a bash background job:

```
ping google.com &
```

First I get the process ID, than Bash prints stdout to screen.

```
user@host:~$ ping google.com &
[1] 14004
user@host:~$ PING google.com (173.194.44.66) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ham02s14-in-f2.1e100.net (173.194.44.66): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=26.3 ms
64 bytes from ham02s14-in-f2.1e100.net (173.194.44.66): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=27.4 ms
64 bytes from ham02s14-in-f2.1e100.net (173.194.44.66): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=29.2 ms
...
```

This contradicts everything I read today. I have a standard Debian Jessie setup running GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Can anyone explain this to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

By default, at least for POSIX compliant systems, running a command in background, with `&`, only detaches `stdin`, so you'll be able to run other commands. `stdout` and `stderr` are still attached to the parent shell.

If you don't want to see `stdout` and/or `stderr` you can just redirect them to a file or `/dev/null`:

```
command &>log.txt &                #stdout and stderr to log.txt
command 1>/dev/null &               #stdout to /dev/null, stderr still attached to shell
command 1>output.log 2>error.log &  #stdout to output.log, stderr to error.log
```

Comment: On MacOSX this does not work.

Comment: @OgierSchelvis: Of course it does.

Comment: Is there a way to reattach `stdin` in this case?

Answer (score 10):

Whether stdout of a background process is shown on the terminal is up to you. You can change the behavior with the `stty` utility.

#### Example

The default allows a background process to write to terminal:

```
$ echo Hello &
[1] 25850
Hello
$
```

That behavior can be changed with the `stty` command:

```
$ stty tostop
$ echo Hello &
[2] 25873

[2]+  Stopped                 echo Hello
$
```

With `tostop` specified, the background process is stopped when it attempts to write to stdout.  If you want to allow it to continue, you can bring it back to the foreground:

```
$ fg
echo Hello
Hello
$
```

To switch back, run `stty -tostop`.  After this is run, *new* background jobs that are created will be allowed to write to stdout.  (Existing jobs will  not be affected.)

#### Documentation

`man stty` explains the `tostop` option as follows:

> * [-]tostop
>   stop background jobs that try to write to the terminal

The leading `*` above is used by the man page to identify this option as non-POSIX.